# How do I start Quartz in standalone mode?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

According to [its feature list](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/Features.html) "Quartz can run as a stand-alone program (within its own Java Virtual Machine), to be used via RMI".

I could not find any documentation how to start it in stand-alone mode, however.

"java -jar quartz.jar" does not do anything (there is not even a Main-Class specified in its mainfest).

All the examples in the distribution use Quartz as an embedded library.

So how does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class you're looking for (e.g. the one with `main()` method starting the RMI server) is [org.quartz.impl.QuartzServer](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/impl/QuartzServer.html).

I'll be honest, though, I've never quite understood the benefit of using it this way.

Comment: That class also installs an RMISecurityManager, so you specify a -Djava.security.policy=policyfilename. Without this, it defaults to allowing nothing and the app crashes on start when trying to read system properties.